# How to deploy with large numbers of files in C++ Builder XE6?

Tags: delphi, c++builder, firemonkey, c++builder-xe6

I'm new to cross-platform development, and am deploying a project to both `Windows` and `Mac` using `C++ Builder XE6 with Firemonkey (FMX)`.

I have a large number of files in a large number of folders that should be deployed with the project. Looking at the Embarcadero page on the Deployment Manager [here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Using_the_Deployment_Manager)

and using the Manager a bit, it seems I have to add files individually (or, at the best, in a given folder) at a time. This is really inconvenient, as I have large numbers of folders within several folders to be deployed. It would be much easier to simply select a folder with a recursive include.

Is there a simpler way to setup files for deployment with `C++ Builder XE6`?

Answer (score 1):

how about just copy all your required files to output folder?

create following folder structure: YouApp.app\Contents\MacOS\
and copy there compiled application together with all dependable system files (like libcgunwind.1.0.dylib) and all your files

that is what "deployment" process doing

Comment: Hi Zam, for Mac deployment the program seems to delete any files in the target folder upon each deployment, which means this doesn't work as a one-step strategy. Is there a way to stop the deployment program from clearing the target folder?